# Not enable to use module pattern3 when I have already downloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Goal:
Use the library pattern3.

Problem:
I get a error saying that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pattern'" when I have already downloaded pattern3.

What part am I missing?

Information:
*I'm using Anaconda
*I'm newbie in python

Code:

```
!python --version

!pip install Pattern3


from pattern.web    import Twitter
from pattern.en     import tag
from pattern.vector import KNN, count
```

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please change the imported module from pattern to pattern3? Something like below.

```
from pattern3.en import tag
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please accept the above as answer in case it solved your problem.